# How do I hide an article element so only logged out users see it

Tags: customization, html, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am using twenty seventeen theme. The theme allows to have different sections on homepage based on site pages. I was wondering how I can add make it so only logged out users see a certain page in one of the sections? Basically I have a new user registration page i want to have as one of my sections but I don't want logged in users to see that section, only logged out users.

My page is [jonathanmusiclessons.com](http://jonathanmusiclessons.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking if the user is logged in as stated in the first answer. You simply need to do it the other way.

For example, if you have a link in the menu that should be hidden in case the user is logged in, just add a custom css;

```
.logged_in .menu-class-here{display:none;}
```

That is to hide a menu item.
Now, if you want to restrict the access to a page if the user is logged in, you can simply do a redirect. Here's an example;

```
if ( is_page('slug') && is_user_logged_in() ) { // where slug is the name or slug of the custom page that you want to restrict from logged in users
   wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/desired-page/', 301 ); 
   exit;
}
```

If you want to allow access to the page but hide a certain section from logged in users, you can do something like;

```
if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
  //add the code here that you want to show to non-logged-in users
}
```

**UPDATE**
Add this to functions.php. You need to create a function to redirect and add it

```
function notallowed() {
  global $post;
if ( is_page('hire-the-freelancer') && is_user_logged_in() ) { // where slug is the name or slug of the custom page that you want to restrict from logged in users
   wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com/desired-page/', 301 ); 
   exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'notallowed' );
```

Comment: So I added this code to my functions.php file

if ( is_page('new-user-registration') && is_user_logged_in() ) { // where slug is the name or slug of the custom page that you want to restrict from logged in users
   wp_redirect( 'http://www.jonathanmusiclessons.com/methods-books/', 301 ); 
   exit;
}
but it didn't redirect the panel from my homepage. Twenty seventeen creates panels based on pages you assign to sections. I want to be able to redirect users to see a different page in the last section on my home page so the only people who see user registration are non logged in users

Comment: You have to do it as a function. See edited answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. unfortunately the code I added to my functions file didn't work. I replaced the original code I put in with the new code you added and it still didn't work. I also tried having both sets of code in there and still didn't work. I'm at a loss... my site is http://jonathanmusiclessons.com

Comment: Did you replace the slug? I forgot to use yours

Comment: Yes I did I put my slug 'new-user-registration'

Comment: function notallowed() {
  global $post;
if ( is_page('new-user-registration') && is_user_logged_in() ) { // where slug is the name or slug of the custom page that you want to restrict from logged in users
   wp_redirect( 'http://www.jonathanmusiclessons.com/methods-books/', 301 ); 
   exit;
}
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'notallowed' );

all added to functions.php

Comment: What does it show? I can't test it in your site cause I am not logged in. But Im trying it in twenty seventeen theme and its working fine. Also, you should add http://www or http:// in the url to where it should redirect. Also, there is a semi colon after your url. There should be not.

Comment: There is http://www it just didn't show up in my comment. And it looks like a semi colon but there isn't. It just still shows the page.

Comment: I can give you a username and password. There is nothing on my site that is sensitive. 
Username - jplouffe1122
Password - teacher1122

This is a customer login

Comment: Hmm.. it seems the code is working as I got redirect. I logged in, then visited this link http://www.jonathanmusiclessons.com/new-user-registration/ and got redirected to http://www.jonathanmusiclessons.com/methods-books/

Comment: I see where we are getting confused.  If you scroll down on my home page you will see different panels. those are some of my pages. The last panel is the new user reg page. So I actually want the panel on my homepage at the bottom to be the methods books panel when a user is logged in, but the new user registration page when not logged in.

Comment: My bad. Since you are not doing this through a template, then use a plugin. i believe you are using a visual composer. This is the proper plugin for this https://wordpress.org/plugins/member-content-visibility/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using the built-in [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) wordpress function :)

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
  // content for non-authenticated users
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to do this for users logged out though. I want the page to be displayed to everyone except for logged in users. If you are logged in, it is as if the page isn't even there.

Comment: I've just edited the answer to fit your comment above.